# Int overflow on 32-bit systems

Tags: go

This is my test function.

```
if -1 != cmp(2<<32, keys[2].Distance(keys[5])) {
        t.Errorf("2<<32 should be smaller")
    }
```

it results in the folllowing error

> constant 8589934592 overflows int

Is it possible to make this work on a 32 bit system?

edit: also this is the Distance function for comparing keys

```
// Distance returns the distance metric in this key space
func (s *xorKeySpace) Distance(k1, k2 Key) *big.Int {
    // XOR the keys
    k3 := XOR(k1.Bytes, k2.Bytes)

    // interpret it as an integer
    dist := big.NewInt(0).SetBytes(k3)
    return dist
}
```

Comment: are you sure the golang version you're using is 64 bit? according to the docs on 64 bit go int should be 64 bit

Comment: I just checked on a 64 bit version of go and there's no problem with 2<<32 as an int

Comment: @sourcey Run `go version` , what is the output on your machine.

Comment: i might be on a 32 bit actually. go -v says 'go version go1.3.1 darwin/386'. Is it possible to make this work on a 32 bit system?

Comment: @sourcey can you modify your code to use int64 explicitly? if so - you're good to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you work on an 64bit int, the best way is to ensure the size by using `uint64`

```
type Key int64 // or uint64
```

Assuming key is defined to be int, otherwise just change all your function signatures from `int` to `int64`.